# how to store values in each array element of an array?

Tags: perl

```
my @someones;
my $xpath = q(//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div);   
for my $i (0,2..20)  
{      
my @nodes = split qr'/', $xpath;      
$nodes[16] .= "[$i]" unless 0 == $i;      
#say join '/', @nodes; } 
@somenames = join('/',@nodes); 
print "\n"; 
print @somenames ; 
}
```

output:

```
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[9]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[10]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[12]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[13]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[14]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[15]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[16]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[17]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[18]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[19]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]
/div/div[20]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
```

After executing the above snippet, all the 20 values are stored in a single element (i.e., $somenames[0]). But i want to store in each array element, say `for i=0,$somenames[0];` `for i=2,$somenames[2];` so on till `for i=20,$somenames[20]`. how can i do it ? and also if i print @somenames outside the for loop, it prints only 20th element.how to store each value in each element of an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. Perhaps this is what you want:

```
# Assign the right side to the $i'th element of @somenames
$somenames[$i] = join('/',@nodes);
```

or

```
# Add an element to the end of @somenames
push @somenames, join('/',@nodes);
```

Comment: @ Dondi Michael Stroma: actually i missed a $ symbol eithin []. Thank U :)

Answer (score 0):

See this code to show you how to store array to array >>

***Script:***

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @a;

@{$a[0]} = (1, 2, 3);
@{$a[1]} = (5, 6, 7);

print Dumper(@a);
```

***Output:***

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          5,
          6,
          7
        ];
```

Test the above code [here](http://ideone.com/7dZUy).

Answer (score 0):

[push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) populates an array. For example:

```
perl -le '$str="1 2 3 4 5";push @vals,split / /,$str;print join ":",@vals'
1:2:3:4:5
```